# Count the number of rows each month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server. I've a following table `Orders`:

```
Orders (Id, ItemId, CustomerId, Quantity, OrderDateTime)
```

I want to count the number of orders each month. I've written 2 of the following query.

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(OrderDateTime) AS MonthCol, 
    YEAR(OrderDateTime) AS YearCol, 
    COUNT(id) AS OrderCount
FROM 
    Orders
WHERE 
    OrderDateTime >= '2000' AND OrderDateTime <= '2018'
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(OrderDateTime), MONTH(OrderDateTime)
ORDER BY 
    YearCol, MonthCol
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(mm, OrderDateTime) AS Month, 
    COUNT(*) AS OrderCount
FROM 
    Orders
WHERE
    OrderDateTime >= '2000' AND OrderDateTime <= '2018'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(mm, OrderDateTime)
```

Issue with both queries is that I'm not getting the columns with 0 orders. How will I get it?

Comment: How can you have zero orders in an order table?

Comment: Aside: Had you searched for `[tsql] missing months` you would have likely found a suitable answer.

Comment: yes, looks like its not possible. :(

Answer (score 1):

SQL will not give you data about months and year which do not exist as rows. To get 0 order rows you'd need to right join the results with a calendar table containing all needed months and years or you can also use a tally table.

```
Select T.MonthCol, T.YearCol,OrderCount= COALESCE(OrderCount,0)
from
(
SELECT MONTH(OrderDateTime) AS MonthCol, YEAR(OrderDateTime) AS YearCol, count(id) AS OrderCount
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDateTime >= '2000' AND OrderDateTime <= '2018'
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDateTime), MONTH(OrderDateTime)
ORDER BY YearCol, MonthCol)
P
RIGHT JOIN
(
select * from 
( values (2000),(2001),(2002),(2003),(2004),(2005),(2006),(2007),(2008))v(YearCol)
cross join
( values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))u(MonthCol)
)T
on P.MonthCol=T.MonthCol
and P.YearCol=T.YearCol
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use a recursive CTE for this -- this gives pretty easy flexibility on the range you want:

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2000-01-01' as date) dte
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < '2018-12-01'
     )
select year(OrderDateTime) AS year,
       month(OrderDateTime) AS month,
       count(o.id) as OrderCount
from dates left join
     orders o
     on d.OrderDateTime >= dates.dte and
        d.OrderDateTime < dateadd(month, 1, dates.dte)
group by year(OrderDateTime), month(OrderDateTime)
order by year(OrderDateTime), month(OrderDateTime)
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Notes:

- This uses the `JOIN` to do the filtering.  This makes it safer to change the range that you are looking for.
- I find the `year()` and `month()` functions to be more convenient `datepart()`.
- When using date parts, spell them out.  Why waste brain power trying to remember if `mm` really means months or minutes?
- I added an `order by`.  Presumably you want the results  in chronological order.